# Grails GSP view won't output variable

Tags: grails, gsp

I got view like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">    
<S:Body>      
    <ns2:${servicename}Response xmlns:ns2="http://ws/">  
          <g:each in="${result}" var="record">
            <return>
          <g:each in="${parameters}" var="parameter">
              <${parameter.name}>${record[parameter.name]}</${parameter.name}>
          </g:each>
            </return>
          </g:each>         
    </ns2:${servicename}Response>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

And it renders like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">    
<S:Body>      
    <ns2:${servicename}Response xmlns:ns2="http://ws/">  

            <return>

              <column1>updated</column1>

              <column2>update</column2>

              <id>1</id>

            </return>

    </ns2:${servicename}Response>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

as you can see, servicename variable is not replaced inside of element name with namespace. i tried to hack it several ways like passing the whole ns:servicename as variable, but nothing helped, there were always some undesirable side effects. How can i do this? i just want to replace the variable without additional validation/processing...

Comment: Please show how you call `render` in your controller. Could it be a typo (for example `serviceName`) ?

Comment: [result: rs, servicename: service.name, parameters: service.getOutputParameters()] cant be a typo though - it works if i place it outside the tag

Comment: if it was a typo then ${servicename} (were it proper syntax in this spot) would just render out as <ns:Response i.e. as an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">    
<S:Body>      
    <%= """<ns2:${servicename}Response xmlns:ns2="http://ws/">""" %>  
          <g:each in="${result}" var="record">
            <return>
          <g:each in="${parameters}" var="parameter">
              <${parameter.name}>${record[parameter.name]}</${parameter.name}>
          </g:each>
            </return>
          </g:each>         
    <%= """</ns2:${servicename}Response>""" %>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: thanks i tried something similar before and now i tried even this exact solution, but the problem is that now it omits the first line with the xml definition (dont know why) as well as removes empty lines (this one would be actually slightly benefical though)

Comment: even if i use <%= """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>""" %>, doesnt help